# SimpleDateFormat parses date string to wrong value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, simpledateformat

I have a date input that reaches the Controller and it performs a conversion from String to Date.

The problem is, the mapping method always returns one day less than I'd expect. If I pass `30/12/2010` it returns a Date object with `29/12/2010` as its value.

I have solved it with a small method that adds a day after the Mapper but I don't know if it is the most correct way:

```
public class DateMapperImpl implements DateMapper {

    @Override
    public String dateToString(Date date, String format) {
        return date != null ? new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Date stringToDate(String date, String format) {
        try {
            return date != null ? addDayDate(new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(date)) : null;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    public Date addDayDate(Date fecha) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(fecha);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it properly?

**SOLUTION**

I already found the solution. In my case it has been necessary to add this method in the Application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BooksApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BooksApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for the answers because they guided me to look for information with a different mindset.

Comment: What's the value of `format`?

Comment: "dd/MM/yyyy". The dates I add 30/12/2010 and save in MySQL 29/12/2010. When translating, this changed the format of the date in the post.

Comment: I'm sorry but your problem is not reproducible. I just compiled your code, ran it and it works. (Expect that it now adds one day on top. Removing that call its perfect)

Comment: There is one possible reason for it, as you are talking about MySQL, I'd guess it's a time zone Issue. `30/12/2010 00:00` minus 1 hour is...

Comment: The issue is with timeZone most probably. If you can show the code from where you are calling, it will be better.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).